Convergence of a recursively defined array.
Let $\beta \in (0,1)$ and let $(u_n(k))_{n,k 
\geq 0}$ be recursively defined by $u_0(k) = \mathbf 1_{k=0}$ and, for $n, k \geq 0$ :
$$u_{n+1}(k) = \beta u_n(k-1) \mathbf 1_{k \geq 1} + (1-\beta) \frac{u_n(k) e ^{-k}}{w_n}, \text{ where }  w_n = \sum_{k \geq 0} u_n(k) e ^{-k}$$
This can serve as a basic model for mutation (the first summand, acting by translation) and selection (the second summand), where $u_n(k)$ is interpreted as the fraction of the population sharing the fitness $k$ at time $n$ and fitness is discrete-valued.
It is not difficult to guess the pointwise limit of the sequences $(u_n(k))_{k\geq 0}$ as $n \to \infty$, more precisely,  setting
$$\pi(k) = \left(\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{\beta}{1-e^{-j}} \right) \pi(0) \text{  where  } \pi(0) =\frac{1}{\sum_{k \geq 0} \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{\beta}{1-e^{-j}}}$$
we conjecture that the following (backed by numerical computations)  holds:
$$u_n(k) \to \pi(k), \text{ as } n \to \infty, \text{ for any fixed } k \geq 0$$
but have been unable so far to prove it (what we tried : find some monotonicity in the system, find a norm for which the map that sends $u_n$ to $u_{n+1}$ is a contraction).
My question :

How to prove the convergence of $u_n(k)$ as $n \to \infty$ for any fixed $k$?

or (this is equivalent):

How to prove the convergence of $w_n$ as $n \to \infty$?

More generally, I am interested in tools that could be useful to prove such convergence statements
--
This model is related to the one in this question.
